# C++ Class Access Management

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I'm developing a game using OpenGL. I have a `Game` class that contains all the environment variables (by environment, I mean things like gravity or tile sets). There's only one `Game` object. I also have another class called `Entity`, which contains properties to display objects on the screen.

I'm finding myself needing access to more and more `Game` variables in my `Entity` class. At the moment i'm just using parameters to pass data into each function, but I'm considering just passing a pointer to the `Game` class? Is there anything wrong with that? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is good practice. It is good idea to replace a group of parameters with a [parameter object](http://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html).

Just make sure that `Game` remains cohesive. The variables contained within `Game` should be related.

Answer (score 0):

Make Entity a Friend of the Game class.

Please see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/465sdshe.aspx

Note:  If this is ever done in C#, there isn't a friend keyword or exact equivalent.